# Issue trying to insert a new column in a table layout

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
ALTER TABLE services_api ADD api_url VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL AFTER;
```

But Error Getting

MySQL said:

> Documentation
>   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: You need a column name after `AFTER`. What column are you trying to put this new column after?

Comment: If you just want to add it at the end, leave out `AFTER`.